# how to change form input name prefix in yii2 active form

Tags: php, yii2

code is here

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'machine_name') ?>
```

and it will gives

```
<input type="text" id="machine-machine_name" class="form-control" name="Machine[machine_name]" maxlength="255" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off">
```

and i want to change

```
name="Machine[machine_name]"
```

to

```
name="something_else[machine_name]"
```

**something_else** is dymanic for all form fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This prefix comes from [`formName()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#formName()-detail). You can override this method in your model (`Machine`) to provide custom prefix:

```
public function formName() {
    return 'something_else';
}
```